# TexMaker showing old PDF using XeLaTeX on Ubuntu

Tags: xetex, compiling, ubuntu

I recently installed TexLive on Ubuntu 16.04 along with TexMaker. I downloaded a file and it compiles and produces a PDF when I run it through the command line with `xelatex file_name.xtx`. However, when I try to edit it on TexMaker, the file compiles the first time and then subsequent updates are not rendered. I have already done `Tools -> XeLaTeX` and I have tried using third party PDF software but to no avail.

Is there some sort of a path I need to setup?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Possibly your compile is not set to trigger an update in the viewer - compiling and updating the PDF viewer are distinct operations in TeXmaker.  What do you mean by "I have tried using third party PDF software but to no avail." if you open the PDF in a non-locking viewer (e.g. Okular or Sumatra but definitely not Adobe) then the PDF in that viewer should update automatically (**if** the file compiles successfully).

Comment: @DaiBowen Alright I will try that but I want to note that I have tried using PDFLaTeX and the built-in viewer seems to work fine. For some reason it does work with XeLaTeX

Comment: @DaiBowen Well after I tried Okular, the build happens but gives me the error: Log file not found. I did a little bit of googling and have tried creating a log file with the same name but that does not seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "the build happens but gives me the error: Log file not found" if you have an error doesn't that mean the file has not correctly compiled?  If you compile successfully then the PDF should happily update in an external viewer - can you be clear, is your problem related to the viewer in TeXmaker alone or with any viewer failing to update (and thus a compilation problem).  Side questions: what OS are you using and which TeX distribution?

Comment: @DaiBowen Ubuntu (in the question). Hence, TeX Live (elimination). @OP Please provide exact text of error messages and some minimal code which produces them. Is it that TeXmaker cannot file the `.log` but the `.log` is produced? If so, does it end in an error? Or can the `.log` not be written, which would mean compilation definitely did not succeed?

Comment: @DaiBowen I phrased my question in a terrible manner. Let me try again: so after I tried using Okular, the error of "File not found" stopped and instead it gave me an error of "Log file not found". However, if I run the "View PDF" command, I can see the PDF generated, but making any subsequent changes does not update the PDF with the same "Log file not found" error occurring. So I tried creating a blank document with XeLaTeX and found that everything worked fine. I was initially trying to use a resume template from [here](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume) which gives this error.

Comment: @cfr Please read the above, it won't let me tag two people. Thanks

Comment: The first thing I would do is make sure your file has a `.tex` extension. No idea what `.xtx` is supposed to be. Maybe it is just to prevent its being overwritten accidentally or something. Please post the complete error message and describe the setup. Do you have all the files downloaded in one directory with your `.tex` file? What is the contents of the `.tex` file?

Comment: Oh, dear. I wouldn't use that class, if I were you. The author gets some pretty basic stuff wrong. Not the worst example, but still poor.

Comment: @cfr Ahhh, it seems like changing the .xtx extension to .tex extension seems to fix the problem. If you want to post that as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted. Also can you please elaborate on what the author does wrong, just curious. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.xtx` is not a standard extension that I'm aware of. Make sure that the version of the template you are trying to compile has the `.tex` extension.

I would not use this class because its author makes some fairly basic mistakes which are likely to cause you headaches whose cause will seem deeply mysterious.

The following are some selected highlights.

- AU uses `\centering{}`. But `\centering` does not take an argument. It sets all text in the current group, up until the last paragraph break in that group, centre, unless a subsequent command cancels the effect.
- AU defines macros in ways which introduce spurious spaces. In some cases, these will not affect the typeset output, but in others they may do and such problems are notoriously difficult to debug.
- AU loads `hyperref` but does nothing to ensure that it is the last package loaded bar specific exceptions. Indeed, the class itself loads other packages later, which it ought not.
- AU uses `\usepackage` rather than `\RequirePackage` in a `.cls` which may not do anything terrible, but is bad practice and confusing.
- AU defines a single option for the class, `print`, which appears to do nothing but define `\@cv@print` to be empty. This macro is never mentioned again.
- AU makes the class dependent on particular fonts. It cannot use other fonts.
- AU makes the class depend on a particular bibliographic package. It is incompatible with, for example, Biblatex.
- AU uses rigid spaces rather than flexible glue. Since the document is intended to be only 1 side long, this may be less of an issue, but it will make it harder to produce a nicely-formatted single-page result.
- AU hard-codes settings such as the locale used to typeset the date, but the document is formatted for a different locale's paper and using a different locale's hyphenation patterns.

Consider the following example:

```
% Descriptors command
\newcommand{\descript}[1]{
\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}
```

This will do the following:

- typeset a space;
- change colour;
- switch all following text in the current group to ragged right, small-caps in Raleway-Medium 11pt with 13pt `\baselineskip` until further notice;
- typeset the argument;
- possibly typeset a space;
- insert a line break [badly, but partially mitigated by the ragged right];
- typeset another space, probably gobbled;
- switch all following text in current group to the default font (without changing the size) until further notice.

Here's a slightly adapted minimal example demonstrating these issues. I've changed `subheadings` to `blue` rather than copy the colour definition and I've deleted the path setting for the font so I can use the version installed on my system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,fontspec,kantlipsum}
% Descriptors command
\newcommand{\descript}[1]{
\color{blue}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}
\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\descript{Description}

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: problems illustrated]

Note: the second paragraph is in blue, is not justified and is in a larger font than the first. This is probably not what you'd expect and unlikely to be what is wanted. Note also that the heading appears too close to the previous paragraph in comparison with the one following.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and the extended detail of the class. I will deliberate whether I want to use the class or not.